# Difference of binomial sums

Tags: combinatorics

is there a way to end up with a compact expression for the difference $(a-b)^j-(c-b)^j$ with $j$ an integer greater or equal than $0$?

Comment: This expression seems compact enough.

Comment: Apply the binomial theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I have already applied the binomial theorem and I end up with $\sum_{k=0}^jb^k(a-c)^{j-k}$ which is still not so useful for my purposes. What I need would be an expression valid for each $j$, the ideal, yet impossible, is $(a-c)^j$.